# On clicking edit link in wordpress template file display blank page

Tags: wordpress

This is my edit link in template file.

```
 <a href=" http://plotsup.com/plotsup_plot/post-service/?ser_edit=6935"><?php   

      _e('Edit','wpestate');
   ?></a>
```

But when I click On that link It display blank page? What will be the possible reason?

Comment: The reason could be an error in the script you are calling. Look at the error log of your web server. Turn on error reporting in this script. Do basic debugging.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider...Why on earth would anyone do "basic debugging" when people on Stack Overflow will do all the work for them? ;-)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ok I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the "u" of user_edit is missing